# create workgroup and join the same workgroup from Linux

Tags: linux, samba, workgroup

Is it possible to create "workgroup" in  a linux machine and join the same linux machine into that workgroup?

my understanding:
smb.conf in /etc/samba/ have an entry name workgroup which can be filled with Actual work group name , say XYZ. This is for connecting with the existing workgroup XYZ?

But, I wish to create a new workgroup and same created machine(linux) to join the workgroup.?
Then I should be able to add any computer to this workgroup?
Please let me know the configuration details for the same.

Thanks!

Comment: @Massimo,@Zoredache: Thanks!. One doubt: What should be the security value? 1. can it be domain? Or it should be any other specific value?

Answer (score 4):

There is not special commands to be part of a work group.  Simply adjust the workgroup setting to the name you want.

```
#smb.conf
[global]
   workgroup = example
```

A workgroup by definition allows anyone to be a member.  Basically a work group is just a name that each computer will announce in addition to their computer name.  See the [netbios name service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NetBIOS#Name_service).

Comment: Thanks!. One qn: What should be the security value? 1. can it be domain? Or it should be any other specific value.

Answer (score 2):

You don't "create" or "join" a workgroup, even when using Windows; a workgroup exists whenever there is at least one computer on the network which says "I am in workgroup X", and ceases to exist when there are no more of them.

If you set your computer's workgroup to some name, this is all that is needed for that workgroup to come to life.